# How to identify primary key column in DB2 version 7.1

Tags: db2, db2-400

I am using DB2 version7.1 and trying to query the primary key column name for one of my requirement. I tried googling but could not get anything related to DB2 7.1.

I don't know much about DB2, hence seeking assistance in finding the primary key column from BD2 version 7.1. Looking forward to positive assistance on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Db2 for i-Series (formerly AS/400) as suggested by the db2-400 tag you put on the question, check the catalog QSYS2.SYSCST - it has a column CONSTRAINT_TYPE whose value is 'P' for primary key. You may need to join with other catalog objects (exammple QSYS2.SYSTABLES, QSYS2.SYSCOLUMNS) depending on the details of what you seek.

The Knowledge center for Db2 for i series R7.1 is still [online](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatsyscst.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how old the application is, you might not be able to find this in your SQL catalog. Unfortunately, many (most?) RPG applications do not use the full power of the DB2 database including indexes, views and constraints. this is changing slowly, but most likely you are going to have to look for logical files with unique keys. There may not be a Primary Key defined. You can look in the SQL catalog, but if you don't find what you are looking for, the following is more likely to help.

1. Find the logical files associated with the physical file (table) using `DSPDBR <table name>`. You can press F4 to prompt for parameters if you don't know what the command line should look like.
2. If you can find the source for the logical files (likely in source file QDDSSRC), inspect that, and if it has the keyword `UNIQUE` above the record format line, then this could be considered a primary key, or at least a unique key. Make sure there is no record selection towards the bottom of the source. There could be multiple logical files like this.
3. Another way to determine if a logical file has a unique key is to use the `DSPFD <logical file>` command. Then search the resulting screen for 'Unique'. The screen should look something like this:

```
File  . . . . . :   QPDSPFD                                             
Control . . . . .   __________                                                     
Find  . . . . . .   Unique                                              
*...+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6....+....7..  
   Access path maintenance . . . . . . . . . . : MAINT      *IMMED      
   Unique key values required  . . . . . . . . : UNIQUE     Yes         
   Select/omit specified . . . . . . . . . . . :            No          
   Access path journaled . . . . . . . . . . . :            No          
   Access path . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            Keyed       
   Number of key fields  . . . . . . . . . . . :              3         
   Record format . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            JCNCXR      
     Key field . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            XFNCMNO     
       Sequence  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            Ascending   
       Sign specified  . . . . . . . . . . . . :            SIGNED      
       Zone/digit specified  . . . . . . . . . :            *NONE       
       Alternative collating sequence  . . . . :            No          
     Key field . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            XFJOBYR     
       Sequence  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            Ascending   
       Sign specified  . . . . . . . . . . . . :            SIGNED      
       Zone/digit specified  . . . . . . . . . :            *NONE       
       Alternative collating sequence  . . . . :            No          
     Key field . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            XFJOBNO     
       Sequence  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :            Ascending
```

The line `Unique key values required  . . . . . . . . : UNIQUE     Yes` indicates that the logical file contains a unique key. The following line `Select/omit specified . . . . . . . . . . . :            No` indicates that there is no record selection logic in the logical file, so it contains all the records in the physical file. and the lines at the bottom show the key fields in order. This is as close to a primary key as you can get with logical files. Since every logical file related to a physical file can have a unique key, most applications will use naming to identify which is the primary key sometimes this will be a L00 or L01 suffix on the file name.

To complicate matters even further, the physical file itself can be keyed uniquely. You can look at the source or use `DSPFD <physical file>` to determine that as well.

These are some unique things about DB2 for i that are not available in the other flavors of DB2. And, it used to be that RPG programmers used physical and logical files exclusively rather than the SQL nature of the DB2 database.